# Distinct in CouchDB with input keys

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Given documents like:

```
[
{"id":1, "category": "cat1", "type": "type1", "line": "line1"},
{"id":2, "category": "cat1", "type": "type1", "line": "line1"},
{"id":3, "category": "cat1", "type": "type2", "line": "line1"},
{"id":4, "category": "cat1", "type": "type1", "line": "line2"},
{"id":5, "category": "cat2", "type": "type1", "line": "line2"},
{"id":6, "category": "cat2", "type": "type1", "line": "line3"}
]
```

I want to be able to pass in the category and type keys and get back the distinct lines e.g. pass in keys of `"cat1"` and `"type1"` and get back `["line1", "line2"]` or pass in `"cat2"` and `"type1"` and get back `["line2", "line3"]`

Easier enough if I am **not** passing in keys:

**map**

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.line]);
}
```

**reduce**

```
function(keys, values) {
  return null;
}
```

I am using group: true, but stumped on how to handle this when passing in keys.

PS, using node and nano so query looks similar to:

```
db.view('catalog', 'lines', {key: ['cat1', 'type1'], group: true}, function (err, body) {
...
});
```

Comment: Why do you have your key wrapped in an array? (ie: `[doc.line]` instead of just `doc.line`)

Comment: Also, why bother having a reduce function at all?

Comment: I am actually passing through more than 1 key into the view: {key: ['cat1', 'type1'], group: true} - I am using group = true and the reduce. This has been the best practice I have seen

Comment: reduce is needed for the group

Comment: Ended up using a list function and processing request params in there

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to pass in the category and type keys and get back the distinct lines i.e. pass in keys of "cat1" and "type1" and get back ["line1", "line2"] or pass in "cat2" and "type1" and get back ["line2", "line3"]

You can get that by querying the following `map` and `reduce` with the right parameters:

**map**

```
function(o) {
  emit([o.category, o.type, o.line]);
}
```

**reduce**

```
_count
```

**queries**

For "cat1" and "type1":

```
/mydb/_design/mydesign/myview?group=true&startkey=["cat1","type1"]&endkey=["cat1","type1",{}]

{"rows":[
{"key":["cat1","type1","line1"],"value":2},
{"key":["cat1","type1","line2"],"value":1}
]}
```

For "cat2" and "type1":

```
/mydb/_design/mydesign/myview?group=true&startkey=["cat2","type1"]&endkey=["cat2","type1",{}]

{"rows":[
{"key":["cat2","type1","line2"],"value":1},
{"key":["cat2","type1","line3"],"value":1}
]}
```